# Is it possible to share 2SXC Content modules between portals on the same DNN instance?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

2sxc 11.x / DNN 9.x

I have a DNN instance with a portal with lots of Content modules with different Content Types and Templates. I'm going to be making a second portal that is related to the first portal and there is some shared content. Is it possible to allow the first portal to share it's 2SXC content types and templates with the second, new portal? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a LOT of ways to do this, and unfortunately there is no good guidance document .

Your scenario sounds like what you would need Ghost-types for: one app creates the real type, the other app just has a ghost-reference for the original type. This is a common way to solve this - and yes, it's a very well kept secret .

But I went ahead and created a checklist, just for you  https://azing.org/2sxc/r/Pj4GMYY5